# Magento 2.0 - SASS and Bootstrap

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sass

Is anybody aware of a Magento 2 theme based on SASS and Bootstrap 3 or 4?  I found this SASS based theme https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass , but it's using LESS.  How much effort would it take to convert it to bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

I have not found a publicly available base theme using both Sass and Bootstrap for Magento 2 yet.

According to Alan Kent, [Magento is planning to move to Sass in the future](https://alankent.me/2016/05/21/magento-2-community-project-moving-from-less-to-sass/), but it hasn't happened yet. Currently this proposed move takes the form of [a forum thread](https://community.magento.com/t5/Less-to-Sass-Community-Project/bd-p/less-to-sass), and [this base Magento 2 Sass theme from Snowdogs](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass). This theme does not incorporate Bootstrap, however.

The Snowdogs Blank theme is pretty nice and I'm building on it, but I found their [Frontools](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools) alternative build project complicated and too unwieldy for our purposes. I'm creating [an extension that compiles Sass](https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-sass-preprocessor) as part of the normal Magento 2 deploy process instead.

I am in the process of incorporating Bootstrap 3 Sass into a Magento 2 base theme, using the Snowdogs Blank Sass Theme as a starting point, but I'm a long way off from completing it.

In addition to the issues of re-stying everything (including changing the HTML DOM structure) to make the best use of Bootstrap's base components and grid, the Magento UI library has it's own set of Modal windows and other JS features that will take a significant amount of work to convert to be "full Bootstrap". I hope to eventually release a base theme when I get it there, but that's all the help I can be at the moment.

I have looked at some paid themes like [Paco](https://themeforest.net/item/paco-responsive-multipurpose-magento-2-theme/16569876) for inspiration on good ways to incorporate Bootstrap - but they use the LESS version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you f@thaddeusmt for the detailed response.  You've confirmed my suspicions that removing the UI library and applying bootstrap instead would be a lot of work.  What are your thoughts on using something like the Paco theme that is Bootstrap + Less, then using this Less to SASS conversion tool https://rubygems.org/gems/less2sass ?  It might get us most of the way there.

Comment: If the LESS-to-SASS conversion tools work well, that could be nice, but I haven't tried that. Seems like it would depend a lot on the quality and extent of the Paco code, which I have not investigated closely. Did they update the Magento UI elements too? Or did they just include the Bootstrap base CSS?